# Showing elimination in the equation

Tags: equations

I want show solving process. So I have for example  `Y=(x-2)y / y =x-2` . I want draw a line over `y` that show as eliminated as problem be solved. How can I do?

Comment: Have you tried the `cancel` package? For example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107671/10898 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105905/10898

Comment: Yes. This is duplicated. Must I delete this post or doing anything else?